# Access Split column data w semi-colon into normalize table structure

Tags: vba, ms-access, split, normalize

I have a table, which was pulled out of some XML data.  I'm trying to do a cross reference, so I can line out a plan for organizing the data.  This 1 table has a list of variables.  Fields of different data types, computations, as well as dialogs. One of the columns has options.  If the data type of the variable is a dialog, its options has a list of variables, separated by a semi-colon.

So the main table has a structure like so:

[image: XML Table Image]

For the dialog records I need to look through their options column and insert records into a normalized table.  For each field, in that column, I want to add a record with that dialog name, and the ID of the row in that table (I added a PK to the table). For instance, in the dialog record, Options column, there is a field in there called BusinessName TE.  I need to search this main table for the PK ID of the row that has a variable name of the same.  I need to put that record's ID with the name of the dialog, and insert both into a new table I set up.  This will create a cross reference for me, so I can know which variables are being used by which dialogs.

I appreciate any help anyone can give.  I see stuff about using a split function, arrays and looping through to get each value, but the examples I'm finding are for strings, not a column in a table.

Thanks!

Edit:  Adding in the VBA code I'm working with.  I attached it to a button on a form, just so I could click to run it.

```
Private Sub RunParse_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim sqlStr, insertSQL, arrayVal As String
Dim TestArray As Variant
Dim Options As String
Dim Dialog As String
Dim FieldName As Long
Dim i As Integer

sqlStr = "SELECT [MASTER Fields].Options,[MASTER Fields].[Variable Name]  FROM [MASTER Fields] WHERE ((([MASTER Fields].[Variable Type])='dialog'));"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    Options = rs.Fields(0)
    Dialog = rs.Fields(1)
    If InStr(Options, ";") Then
        TestArray = Split(Options, ";")

        For i = 0 To UBound(TestArray) - LBound(TestArray) + 1
            If TestArray(i) <> "" Then

                arrayVal = TestArray(i)

                FieldName = DLookup("ID", "MASTER Fields", "[Variable Name] = " & "'" & arrayVal & "'")

                insertSQL = "INSERT INTO FieldTemplatesUse(FID, TemplateAK) " _
                & "VALUES(""" & FieldName & """, """ & Dialog & """)"
                DoCmd.RunSQL (insertSQL)

            End If
        Next i
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop


End Sub
```

right now on the line that says

```
If TestArray(i) <> "" Then
```

creates an error ""

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

---

Another Edit:

Parfait figured out my issue.  I'm posting the final code I am using, in case it helps someone else!  p.s. I added a condition to check if the dlookup is successful, and trap failures in a failures table.  That way I can check those out afterward.

```
Private Sub RunParse_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim sqlStr, insertSQL, arrayVal As String
Dim TestArray As Variant
Dim Options As String
Dim Dialog As String
Dim FieldName As Long
Dim i As Integer

sqlStr = "SELECT [Master Fields].Options,[Master Fields].[Variable Name]  FROM [Master Fields] WHERE ((([Master Fields].[Variable Type])='dialog'));"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF
    Options = rs.Fields(0)
    Dialog = rs.Fields(1)
    If InStr(Options, ";") Then
        TestArray = Split(Options, ";")

        For i = 0 To UBound(TestArray) - LBound(TestArray)
            If TestArray(i) <> "" Then

                arrayVal = TestArray(i)
                If Not (IsNull(DLookup("ID", "Master Fields", "[Variable Name] = " & "'" & arrayVal & "'"))) Then

                    FieldName = DLookup("ID", "Master Fields", "[Variable Name] = " & "'" & arrayVal & "'")

                    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO FieldTemplatesUse(FID, TemplateAK) " _
                    & "VALUES(""" & FieldName & """, """ & Dialog & """)"
                    DoCmd.RunSQL (insertSQL)
                    'MsgBox "Adding ID = " & FieldName & "for Dialog: " & Dialog & "Now"
                Else
                     insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tblFieldsNotFound(Dialog, FieldNotFound) " _
                    & "VALUES(""" & Dialog & """, """ & arrayVal & """)"
                    DoCmd.RunSQL (insertSQL)

                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "All Done!"


End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Is error *subscript out of range*? If so, remove the +1 after `LBound()`.

Comment: Thank you!  That was it!